# Cargar datos en un Select Ajax PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Buen día colegas, espero y puedan apoyarme, busco cargar los registros que tengo en mi BD, en un select mediante ajax, al momento tengo esto sin embargo no me muestra nada, espero y puedan apoyarme.

```js
var mostrarMedidas = $('#unidadmedida').val()
$.ajax({
  url: 'otros/medidas.otros',
  method: 'GET',
  data: mostrarMedidas,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#unidadmedida").append(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id="unidadmedida" data-allow-clear="true"></select>
```

y mi archivo PHP donde tengo mi consulta es esta.

```html
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM ct_unidades_medidas");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    // Aquì, agregaremos opciones
    echo "<option value='".$row['id_unidad_medida']."'>".$row['nombre_unidad']."</option>";
}

?>
```

Espero y puedan apoyarme.

Comment: 2 cosas... que se supone que haces en el archivo php, por que, si solo es un archivo a parte, no hace nada realmente... y la consulta ajax, que se supone que quieres hacer, tampoco hace nada realmente... le dices, dame el val de unidad medida, y metelo.. donde mismo ???

Comment: En el archivo PHP, lo que hago es la consulta para obtener los registros de Medidas, en Ajax busco traer esos registros y mostrarlos en mi input Selec, solo es una idea sin embargo aun no lo encuentro bien

Answer (score 1):

intenta de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'otros/medidas.otros',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {'mostrarMedidas': 1},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#unidadmedida").append(data);
  }
});
```

Usa el método `POST` en lugar de `GET` y el formato `json` en lugar de `html`.

```
<select class="form-select" id="unidadmedida" data-allow-clear="true"></select>
```

Luego, validas los datos en `PHP` y retornas el contenido de la lista, si es que se cumplen las condiciones.

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';

//Preparar una variable vacía
$lista = "";
//Validar si el campo está seteado y es igual a 1
if(isset($_POST['mostrarMedidas']) && $_POST['mostrarMedidas'] == 1) {
  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM ct_unidades_medidas");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    // Aquì, agregaremos opciones
    $lista .= "<option value='".$row['id_unidad_medida']."'>".$row['nombre_unidad']."</option>";
  }
}
//Retornar en formato json la variable vacía o con datos
echo json_encode($lista);
?>
```

Es una alternativa.

Haz pruebas y comenta si tienes alguna dificultad. Recuerda depurar el código en el inspector de tu navegador para corregir posibles errores.

Comment: Perfecto, me muestra los resultados, ya solo quisiera saber como seria que cuando se registre una nueva unidad se cargue automaticamente en mi Select, porque ahorita se muestra cuando recargo la página

Comment: Eso es otro proceso diferente, el tener que guardarlos es otro al como leerlos.

Comment: Envuelve la petición `ajax` en una función y ejecutas esa función al registrar cada nueva unidad. Asegúrate de vaciar el listado antes de ejecutar dicha función para evitar que se "dupliquen" los `option`. Esto lo consigues así `$('#unidadmedida').html("");`. Inténtalo y si tienes alguna duda puntual, te sugiero abrir una nueva pregunta.